# MSSQL Replace string with another string after a certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I am receiving a email id into my sql procedure.I need to replace the email client with a defined string.

Suppose I receive email id such as abc@gmail.com or pqr@yahoo.com or mnz@hotmail.com, in such cases I need to replace @gmail.com / @yahoo.com with a fixed string.

```
abc@gmail.com - abc@outlook.com
pqr@yahoo.com - pqr@outlook.com
mnz@hotmail.com - mnz@outlook.com
```

So the string after @ will be replaced with my defined string irrespective of the data received in procedure.

Tried Replace method but it didn't work. I know that i need to use charindex, substring & left functions to make it work but not getting the right combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it simple here and just use `CHARINDEX` with `LEFT`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET email_id = LEFT(email_id, CHARINDEX('@', email_id) - 1) + 'outlook.com';
```

Comment: received error message as 'The left function requires 2 argument(s).'

Comment: I would add `WHERE email_id LIKE '%@%'`.

Comment: I suppose email id will always contain @ so where condition is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REPLACE()` with `CHARINDEX()` as

```
CREATE TABLE Strings(
  Str VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO Strings VALUES
('abc@gmail.com'),  
('pqr@yahoo.com'),  
('mnz@hotmail.com');

UPDATE Strings
SET Str = REPLACE(Str, SUBSTRING(Str, CHARINDEX('@',Str), LEN(Str)), '@outlook.com');

SELECT *
FROM Strings;
```

Here is also another way

```
UPDATE S
SET S.Str = REPLACE(S.Str, E.V, '@outlook.com')
FROM Strings S JOIN (VALUES('@gmail.com'), ('@hotmail.com'), ('@yahoo.com')) E(V)
ON S.Str LIKE CONCAT('%', E.V, '%');
```

**[Demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4720761ae6fa70654f9e73e4e17fc346)**

**[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=883b371413026727443331175bab74d5)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2017, you can use this as a subquery inside your main query:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + '@outlook.com'
FROM STRING_SPLIT('pqr@yahoo.com', '@');
```

Read more about `FIRST_VALUE`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Read more about `STRING_SPLIT`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**Update**

As @TimBiegeleisen mentioned, Microsoft docs says:

> The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to
>   match the order of the substrings in the input string

To overcome that, we can even rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT value + '@outlook.com'
FROM
(
    SELECT value,
           CHARINDEX('@', 'pqr@yahoo.com') AS atIndex,
           CHARINDEX(value, 'pqr@yahoo.com') AS partIndex
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('pqr@yahoo.com', '@')
) AS K
WHERE K.atIndex > K.partIndex;
```

Comment: If you read the documentation for `STRING_SPLIT` closely, you'll also notice that there are no guarantees about the order of the table.  So, `FIRST_VALUE` may not always work here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Great notice. I have updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following queries replace tbl_name and column_name according to your data:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET column_name = replace(column_name, 'gmail.com', 'outlook.com');    
UPDATE tbl_name SET column_name = replace(column_name, 'yahoo.com', 'outlook.com');    
UPDATE tbl_name SET column_name = replace(column_name, 'hotmail.com', 'outlook.com');
```

Comment: And what about every other domain out there? This won't scale well.

Comment: "BikerDude.HogMail.Comics@42.com" becomes what? Well, "gmail.com" is in there so ... .